# Why is Ansible not failing this string in stdout conditional?

Tags: networking, ansible, conditional-statements, stdout, block

I am running Ansible version 2.7 on Centos7 using the network_cli connection method.

I have a playbook that:

- Instructs a networking device to pull in a new firmware image via TFTP
- Instructs the networking device to calculate the md5 hash value
- Stores the output of the calculation in .stdout
- Has a conditional When: statment that checks for a given md5 value in the .stdout before proceeding with the task block.

No matter what md5 value I give, it always runs the task block.

The conditional statement is:

```
when: '"new_ios_md5" | string in md5_result.stdout'
```

Here is the full playbook:

---

```
- name: UPGRADE SUP8L-E SWITCH FIRMWARE
  hosts: switches
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
   - name: "compliant_ios_version"
     prompt: "What is the compliant IOS version?"
     private: no

   - name: "new_ios_bin"
     prompt: "What is the name of the new IOS file?"
     private: no

   - name: "new_ios_md5"
     prompt: "What is the MD5 value of the new IOS file?"
     private: no

   - name: "should_reboot"
     prompt: "Do you want Ansible to reboot the hosts? (YES or NO)"
     private: no

  tasks:
    - name: GATHER SWITCH FACTS
      ios_facts:

    - name: UPGRADE IOS IMAGE IF NOT COMPLIANT
      block:
      - name: COPY OVER IOS IMAGE
        ios_command:
           commands:
              - command: "copy tftp://X.X.X.X/45-SUP8L-E/{{ new_ios_bin }} bootflash:"
                prompt: '[{{ new_ios_bin }}]'
              answer: "\r"
        vars:
          ansible_command_timeout: 1800

      - name: CHECK MD5 HASH
        ios_command:
           commands:
              - command: "verify /md5 bootflash:{{ new_ios_bin }}"
        register: md5_result
        vars:
          ansible_command_timeout: 300

      - name: CONTINUE UPGRADE IF MD5 HASH MATCHES
        block:
        - name: SETTING BOOT IMAGE
          ios_config:
            lines:
            - no boot system
            - boot system flash bootflash:{{ new_ios_bin }}
            match: none
            save_when: always

        - name: REBOOT SWITCH IF INSTRUCTED
          block:
          - name: REBOOT SWITCH
            ios_command:
               commands:
                  - command: "reload"
                    prompt: '[confirm]'
                    answer: "\r"
            vars:
              ansible_command_timeout: 30

          - name: WAIT FOR SWITCH TO RETURN
            wait_for:
              host: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
              port: 22
              delay: 60
              timeout: 600
            delegate_to: localhost

          - name: GATHER ROUTER FACTS FOR VERIFICATION
            ios_facts:

          - name: ASSERT THAT THE IOS VERSION IS CORRECT
            assert:
              that:
                - compliant_ios_version == ansible_net_version
              msg: "New IOS version matches compliant version. Upgrade successful."

          when: should_reboot == "YES"

        when: '"new_ios_md5" | string in md5_result.stdout'

      when: ansible_net_version != compliant_ios_version
...
```

The other two conditionals in the playbook work as expected. I cannot figure out how to get ansible to fail the when: '"new_ios_md5" | string in md5_result.stdout' conditional and stop the play if the md5 value is wrong.

When you run the play with debug output the value of stdout is:

```
    "stdout": [
".............................................................................................................................................Done!", 
                "verify /md5 (bootflash:cat4500es8-universalk9.SPA.03.10.02.E.152-6.E2.bin) = c1af921dc94080b5e0172dbef42dc6ba"
            ]
```

You can clearly see the calculated md5 in the string but my conditional doesn't seem to care either way.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes around the condition?

Comment: @nwinkler When I remove the single quotes Ansible barks about a syntax error. I changed the line to 

when: new_ios_md5 in md5_result.stdout

Which Ansible accepted, but when running the play and giving a false md5 value for new_ios_md5 it still passes and proceeds with the task block.

Comment: is `"new_ios_md5"` a placeholder -- e.g., in your real playbook that is replaced with a literal md5 hash -- or are you attempting to use a variable there?

Comment: @larsks It's a variable retrieved from a vars_prompt at the beginning of the play. So once the play starts, I type in the appropriate hash value when prompted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
when: '"new_ios_md5" | string in md5_result.stdout'
```

You are looking for the *literal string* "new_ios_md5" inside the variable `md5_result.stdout`.  Since you actually want to refer to the new `new_ios_md5` variable, you ened to remove the quotes around it:

```
when: 'new_ios_md5 | string in md5_result.stdout'
```

Comment: I made the suggested change and now, when providing a valid md5 value, I get:

TASK [SETTING BOOT IMAGE] ******************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/upgrade-cisco-ios-switch-playbook2.yml:49
Trying secret <ansible.parsing.vault.PromptVaultSecret object at 0x7f0ac8547210> for vault_id=default
skipping: [TESTLAB4506] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}

I can see the valid MD5 string in stdout during debug so I don't understand why Ansible doesn't.

Comment: Figured it out with the help of a redditor. ios_command results come back as a list so I had to use stdout[0] which changed the conditional statement to:

when: 'new_ios_md5 in md5_result.stdout[0]'

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to zoredache on reddit for the final solution:

BTW, you know that for most of the various networking commands ios_command the results come back as a list right? So you need to index into the list relative to the command you run.

Say you had this. task

```
ios_command:
    commands:
      - command: "verify /md5 bootflash:{{ new_ios_bin }}"
      - command: show version
      - command: show config
register: results
```

You would have output in the list like this.

```
# results.stdout[0] = verify
# results.stdout[1] = show version
# results.stdout[2] = show config
```

So the correct conditional statement would be:

```
when: 'new_ios_md5 in md5_result.stdout[0]'
```